# How to redirect an outgoing traffic to another address?

Tags: macos, redirect, networking, tcp, proxy

I'd like to redirect specific outgoing TCP traffic to another address.

Say I have an application that tries to establish a connection to a server **aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:99999**.

What I am trying to do is to redirect the application's outgoing traffic to another address (e.g., **ddd.eee.fff.ggg:88888**) without touching the application. Is this possible in Windows or Mac OS X?

Thanks

Comment: What you are asking about is called NAT (Network Address Translation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two cases here:

First if you have **fqdn**, it's easy you just have to resolve it to a different ip via the local `hosts` file.

Second if the application is trying to reach **specific ip address** it's not so simple, and i will mention a way to do it on the system and one without changing anything on the system.

Within the system you have to modify local firewall. I will write you an example command from `iptables` which works on linux systems but sth equivalent you can apply with the software MacOS *(`pf` see the edit on the end)* and Windows have installed. 
What i do below, is to **NAT** the IP i want to change, to a new IP.

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d IP_YOU_WANT_REWRITE --dport PORT -j DNAT --to-destination NEW_IP:NEW_PORT`

In case now you don't want to mess with the host machine at all you can apply a similar NAT rule on your gateway/router, you just NAT the IP you want to change to the new one on the router configuration and your host reach the new one transparently.

edit: As far as i can see osx equivalent to iptables is `pf` so you need to write a similar rule using the `nat` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried searching some relevant posts and found this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223944/pf-port-forwarding-on-os-x-yosemite-to-avoid-block but there's no clear answer there as well :(

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a mac to test a solution but here is the [manual](http://murusfirewall.com/Documentation/OS%20X%20PF%20Manual.pdf) where you can find the `nat` command. You can check also [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/662366/forwarding-ip-address-using-pf) answer.